# Validation of domain rules spanning multiple aggregate roots

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Lets assume we have the following ARs:

- Service - responsible for service configuration.
- DaySchedule - responsible for defining schedule for each day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday ... Sunday) and creating appointments for a calendar day, e.g. 08/15/2020.

```
public class Service : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
   public bool Available { get; private set; }
   public int TimeSlotDuration { get; private set; }
}

public class DaySchedule : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
   public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; }
   public List<Appointment> WorkingHours { get; private set; }
   public List<Appointment> Appointments { get; private set; }
}

public class Appointment : Entity
{
   public Guid ServiceId { get; }
   public int AppointmentStart { get; private set; }
   public int AppointmentEnd { get; private set; }
}
```

In order for Appointment to be correctly created and defined, the appointment duration (the time between AppointmentStart and AppointmentEnd) must not exceed the defined TimeSlotDuration value on Service AR, also service must be available.

Now, the problem that I'm facing is - how do I correctly and efficiently enforce this?

What I'm doing at the moment is the following:

1. Read Service AR, get and extract necessary values.
2. Validate if properties on new Appointment are valid, if not, throw exception.

I guess this works, but are there any better ways? What if I have ***n*** other ARs that I need to check?

What comes to my mind is eventual consistency but I fail to see how I could apply it in my situation. Maybe some sort of a Saga that goes through all aggregates, verifies all the domain rules and once they've all been verified only then insert appointment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, the problem that I'm facing is - how do I correctly and efficiently enforce this?

Aggregates 101: if you have two pieces of information that must be in agreement at all instants, then those two pieces of information should be part of the same aggregate, because any transaction that might change one must also take into account the other.

Two pieces of information that must agree when the system is in equilibrium, but not necessarily while things are changing, can be distributed across two different aggregates.

So that's the first piece that you have to work out  - do your appointments need to be consistent with the service state always? or just when things stop moving?

(In most cases involving human beings, the business answer is "when things stop moving".)

If you need instant agreement, then any time you need to change an appointment, you need to prevent the service from changing "at the same time", and any time you make a change to a service, you also need to consider all of the affected appointments.

That in turn means that either (a) you have only a single lock that all changes go through, or (b) a service and the affected appointments are always locked together.

The name of the pattern where we organize related information so that it can all be locked together is "aggregate".

When you are in this case, that the data always has to be consistent, then the recommended course is to redesign your aggregates so that a single aggregate can maintain the invariant.  This often leads to carving up you domain model in ways that you wouldn't expect -- see Mauro Servienti's talk [All Our Aggregates are Wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkzvQSuYd5I).

Eventual consistency is for the case where the data doesn't need to be consistent while things are changing, so long as things keep changing until the data is consistent.  A common starting point is to detect a possible issue, the escalate the concern to a human being for remediation.

See Rinat Abdullin's work on [evolving process managers](https://abdullin.com/post/ddd-evolving-business-processes-a-la-lokad/), and [Memory, Guesses, and Apologies](http://blogs.msdn.com/pathelland/archive/2007/05/15/memories-guesses-and-apologies.aspx) by Pat Helland.

Answer (score 1):

Generally my approach to this is that any data that an aggregate needs that it does not have has to be provided.

The integration/application concern is where you gather all data and domain objects.  Typically you would not query your aggregates but whichever way you get the data is up to you.  Once you establish that you may indeed book the `Appointment` based on the `Service` availability and duration then you can go ahead.  You may opt for creating some class in the application project to encapsulate the processing for re-use.

What *may* present a "problem" is when the service duration and/or availability changes while you are creating the appointment.  This is a bit of a race condition.  However, this can be mitigated by rather having a future `ExpiryDate` for the service or, should the service attributes change, having some compensating mechanism kick in for each `Appointment` that would need to change as a result.  Here is where a process manager may be useful.

You are going to run into many scenarios where you are dependent on data from outside your aggregate, or even outside your BC.  You need to design each approach based on your requirements.  A flight booking may, for instance, be handled either by first reserving seats and then applying the reservation once the booking is accepted or by allowing multiple bookings for the same seats and the person who completes a booking first wins.  It is a design choice though.